# Правильное создание ASP MVC проекта включающего разные слои

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет!

Ребят строю проект, создал слой сайт - "WEB" - тип asp mvc 5, бизнес слой (BLL) - тип ClassLibrary и еще нужен слой данных (DLL), в котором я добавлю энтити модель сгенерированную с существующей БД.

Вопрос - какого типа проекта должен быть DLL ?

---

в DLL проект я добавил ентити модель сгенерировал ее с реальной БД, затем работаю с бизнес проектом (BLL):

ниже класс BLL проекта, в котором содержиться бизнес логика. К BLL проекту я добавил ссылку на DLL проект.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace BusinessLayer.Record
{
    public class RecordManager  : IDisposable
    {

        //создаю db чтобы работать с DLL
        private DLL.nissanin_AFFEntities db = null;

        //тут будут методы работы с DLL

        //это я так понимаю очистка мусора
        private bool disposed = false;
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (db != null) db.Dispose(); // но у db. есть только перечень таблиц и не более.
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

---

спасибо за ответ.

1. код класса nissanin_AFFEntities или хотя бы его иерархию наследования -  http://joxi.ru/L4QUUxjKTJAqDgUeh0A   -  он сгенерирован студией с базы данных.

### 2 .И еще - какие функции у вас выполняет тот класс, код которого вы продемонстрировали (Record)?

как видите это класс проекта BLL - проекта который управляет бизнес логикой, его функция - брать данные с DLL и отдавать сайту (проект asp mvc  - WEB), ну и обратно принимать данные с сайта и отправлять их на DLL

---

вот:

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DLL
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

```
public partial class nissanin_AFFEntities : DbContext
{
    public nissanin_AFFEntities()
        : base("name=nissanin_AFFEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Avtor> Avtors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AvtorBiography> AvtorBiographies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

}

немного смущает неймспейс, но вряд ли в нем может быть проблема

---

спасибо вам большое за помощь, все оказалось очень банально и стоило кучу времени(

не был подключен EntityFramework пакет в BLL.
Вы не могли бы посоветовать книгу (на русском) где были бы основы.... а то я нахватался уже практического..... но мало понимаю как оно в основе своей работает...

Comment: обычный Class Library. Кстати, тогда уж этот слой должен называться не DLL, а DAL

Comment: @Lifeact покажите код класса nissanin_AFFEntities или хотя бы его иерархию наследования. Проблема, очевидно, там. И еще - какие функции у вас выполняет тот класс, код которого вы продемонстрировали (Record)?

Comment: @Lifeact вы явно что-то напутали. Как можно видеть из приведенного вами кода, класс nissanin_AFFEntities наследуется от DbContext. DbContext в свою очередь должен реализовывать интерфейс IDisposable, а следовательно в нем есть метод Dispose? а следовательно метод Dispose должен также быть и в nissanin_AFFEntities. Прповерьте имена классов

Comment: @Lifeact книги по Entity Framework вы имеете в виду? Честно говоря, сомневаюсь, что они есть, во всяком случае на русском языке. Впрочем, в интернете есть достаточное количество статей по этой ORM

Answer (score 1):

Коментарии кончились, пишу как ответ. Насчет книг - вряд ли, однако у Троелсена в его [книге](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1814-7.html) 23-я глава посвящена этой ORM. Пусть не целая книга, но тоже может быть полезно